# Trying to avoid this error (raise exception KeyError: 'text') , when getting tweets about verizon

Tags: python, twitter

I am getting tweets from twitter about verizon and everthing is good according to the code below, but I do not understand why I am getting error KeyError "text"?

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

# consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
csecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
atoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
asecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        out = open('verizon_twitter_data.txt', 'a+')
        tweet=tweet.encode('utf-8')
        out.write(str(tweet)+"\n")

        print (tweet)

        out.close()
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['verizon', 'vzw','verizzon',    'vrizon','verizonfois',
                        'verzon','verizun','vrzon','veerizon','verrizon', 'veriizon'], languages=["en"])
```

I got this error after some time like an hour or more:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/amjhool2013/Desktop/untitled4/untitled4/main.py", line 32, in <module>
'verzon','verizun','vrzon','veerizon','verrizon', 'veriizon'], languages=["en"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
KeyError: 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to avoid the error on the occasional tweet that fails in the stream, you could create an exception:

```
try:
    tweet = all_data["text"]
    out = open('verizon_twitter_data.txt', 'a+')
    tweet = tweet.encode('utf-8')
    out.write(str(tweet)+"\n")
except KeyError:
    # do something else
```